# Can Touch ID on Mac authenticate sudo in Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, password, sudo, touch-id

Can Touch ID on Mac authenticate sudo in Terminal?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

With macOS Sonoma, there is now a supported option to enable Touch ID for sudo:

> Touch ID can be allowed for sudo with a configuration that persists across software updates using `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local`. See `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local.template` for details.

[What's new for enterprise in macOS Sonoma - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT213893)

1. `sudo cp /etc/pam.d/sudo_local.template /etc/pam.d/sudo_local`
2. `sudo nano /etc/pam.d/sudo_local` and follow the instructions inside, uncommenting the last line of the file by removing the `#` from the start of the line so the file looks like this:

   ```
   # sudo_local: local config file which survives system update and is included for sudo
   # uncomment following line to enable Touch ID for sudo
   auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so
   ```

This will persist through software updates unlike changes to `/etc/pam.d/sudo`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Worth noting if you use DisplayLink that it will still prompt you for password unless you also run `defaults write com.apple.security.authorization ignoreArd -bool TRUE`.

Comment: If you'd like to use this with `tmux`, you would have to install https://github.com/fabianishere/pam_reattach and add that to `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local` as well (assuming you trust the author). The link also documents the problem in detail.

For the same reason, you need to change an iTerm option if you want to use this with iTerm, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355880/513181.

Comment: If I could give comments an upvote I would for Samuel Lindblom's comment!

Answer (score 358):

To allow TouchID on your Mac to authenticate you for `sudo` access instead of a password you need to do the following.

- Open Terminal
- Switch to the root user with `sudo su -`
- Edit the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file with a command-line editor such as `vim` or `nano`
- The contents of this file should look like one of the following examples:

  - ```
    # sudo: auth account password session
    auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
    account    required       pam_permit.so
    password   required       pam_deny.so
    session    required       pam_permit.so
    ```
  - ```
    # sudo: auth account password session
    auth       sufficient     pam_smartcard.so
    auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
    account    required       pam_permit.so
    password   required       pam_deny.so
    session    required       pam_permit.so
    ```
- You need to add an additional `auth` line to the top so it now looks like this:

  ```
  # sudo: auth account password session
  auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so
  auth       sufficient     pam_smartcard.so
  auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
  account    required       pam_permit.so
  password   required       pam_deny.so
  session    required       pam_permit.so
  ```
- Save the file. (**Note:** this file is normally read-only so saving your changes may require you to force the save, e.g. `vim` will require you to use `wq!` when saving)
- Also note that `pam_smartcard.so` may not be present on older MacOS versions.
- Exit from the root user or start a new terminal session.
- Try to use `sudo`, and you should be prompted to authenticate with TouchID as shown below.

  [image: TouchID prompt]
- If you click 'Cancel,' you can just enter your password at the terminal prompt. If you click 'Use Password' you can enter your password in the dialog box.
- If you SSH into your machine it will fall back to just use your password, since you can't send your TouchID fingerprints over SSH.

**Note:**
See [answer by user Pierz below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355880/158188) if you're using iTerm, as there's a setting you need to explicitly change to enable this feature.

**Note:**
Recent MacOS updates may remove the entry. If TouchID stops working for `sudo` then check if the entry was removed and add it back in, following these instructions again.

Comment: Seems to work! Are there any security implications with this?

Comment: This worked only after I did https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355880/158188 (but I did do this first)

Comment: @Znarkus one potential security implication is that, at least in the US, you cannot be compelled to give up a password by a court (it's considered a violation of the 5th amendment), but your biometrics are not secret, so you can absolutely be forced by a court to biometric auth. i'm not sure that's a concern for most people, but it's a good piece of knowledge to have.

Comment: No need for all the steps of doing `sudo su -`, editing, force-saving with `wq!`, and exiting root. Just use `sudo -e /etc/pam.d/sudo` which opens the file in your default editor and seamlessly does all of the required priviledge escalation for you.

Comment: Don't do `wq!`.  Do `w!` first. Test, test, test, _then_ quit vim. If you make a typo you'll be locked out of your account.

Comment: That doesn't seem to "survive" an update of OSX, I had to apply these changes again after an update from 11.5.2 to 11.6. Any idea how to improve the solution to make it more robust?

Comment: It works. Thanks, bro

Answer (score 87):

If you're using iTerm2 (v3.2.8+) you may have seen Touch ID failing to work with sudo in the terminal despite having made the `pam_tid.so` modification as above, and it working in previous versions. This is down to an [advanced feature](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/7608#note_153123852) that seems to be now enabled by default - this needs to be turned off here: **iTerm2->Preferences > Advanced > (Goto the Session heading) > Allow sessions to survive logging out and back in**.

Alternatively you can use this [`pam_reattach`](https://github.com/fabianishere/pam_reattach) module to retain the session feature and TouchID sudo at the same time.

[image: iTerm preferences]

Comment: But if you want to keep sessions restoring feature, you can try [this repo](https://github.com/fabianishere/pam_reattach) with a custom pam module.

Comment: Just tested: When using `pam_reattach`, one needn't either change the setting or restart iTerm — everything works right away! (I haven't tested if sessions "actually survive" since I have no clue how, but I didn't need change the setting).

Comment: The touch ID prompt hides the full-screened hotkey-window. Is there a workaround?

Comment: PSA: __Do not__ typo anything in `/etc/pam.d/sudo`. If you do, you'll have to load up single-user mode to change it back.

Comment: @Michael Alternatively you can enable root via `dsenableroot` which first prompts for your password and then for a new-to-set root password. If you don't have enabled the root user before, that is. ([via](https://superuser.com/a/1233928)) `dsenableroot -d` to deactivate again. ([via](/q/437850))

Comment: @Michael Actually, it is not necessary. The only thing that is needed is to temporarily enable root user on macos and then use 'su' to login in shell as root, and then temporarily `chmod +w /etc/pam.d/sudo`. Now you can fix any typos  and then revert permissions back with `chmod -w /etc/pam.d/sudo`... And then disable root user in macos.

Answer (score 26):

1. TouchID does support elevating privileges, but as of now, it only seems to be supported in Apple's own apps. My guess is that 3rd party apps will have to be updated to support it, unfortunately. I still end up typing in my password a lot.
2. See [@conorgriffin's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306324/11303) for instructions to enable TouchID for sudo.

Answer (score 22):

I have created a simple script that enables sudo to use the TouchID PAM module exactly as conorgriffin explains. It does it in a single script that you can copy-paste to a terminal in it's entirety or use the "`curl` pipe `bash`" shortcut:

`curl -sL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RichardBronosky/31660eb4b0f0ba5e673b9bc3c9148a70/raw/touchid_sudo.sh | bash`

[The complete script](https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/31660eb4b0f0ba5e673b9bc3c9148a70):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

# curl -sL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RichardBronosky/31660eb4b0f0ba5e673b9bc3c9148a70/raw/touchid_sudo.sh | bash
# This script is ready to copy-paste in whole, or just the line above (without the leading #)

# Use TouchID for sudo on modern MacBook Pro machines
# This script adds a single line to the top of the PAM configuration for sudo
# See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/259093/41827 for more info.

touchid_sudo(){
  sudo bash -eu <<'EOF'
  file=/etc/pam.d/sudo
  # A backup file will be created with the pattern /etc/pam.d/.sudo.1
  # (where 1 is the number of backups, so that rerunning this doesn't make you lose your original)
  file_dir="$(dirname "$file")"
  file_name="$(basename "$file")"
  mapfile -t backup_list < <( ls -A "$file_dir"/{,.}"$file_name"* 2>/dev/null )
  backup_count="${#backup_list[@]}"
  backup_ext="$backup_count"
  backup="$file_dir/.$file_name.$backup_ext"
  cp "$file" "$backup" 2>/dev/null || touch "$file" "$backup"

  awk -v is_done='pam_tid' -v rule='auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so' '
  {
    # $1 is the first field
    # !~ means "does not match pattern"
    if($1 !~ /^#.*/){
      line_number_not_counting_comments++
    }
    # $0 is the whole line
    if(line_number_not_counting_comments==1 && $0 !~ is_done){
      print rule
    }
    print
  }' > $file < $backup
EOF
}

touchid_sudo
```

This script demonstrates a few cool patterns that I love to teach people who are new to bash or DevOps.

1. Create a backup file that is numbered rather than simply `.bak` on the end. (It looks gnarly, but that pattern works with whatever is in `$file` and is reusable.
2. To make it safe to do `curl ... | bash`, wrap everything in a function and call it on the last line. That way if the download is interrupted, nothing is (partially) done.
3. Put a call to `sudo bash -eu` in your script so that you don't have tell the user to do it. (`-eu` are short for [errexit and nounset](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash%20errexit%20nounset) and you should be using them!)
4. Single quoting bash heredoc `'EOF'` to prevent premature shell expansion.
5. Making inline `awk` more readable.

Comment: The script above erroered for me: `bash: line 6: 0: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: The script assumes a "modern" version of Bash, @JanKatins. You'll need to install a recent version of `bash` from Homebrew or elsewhere.

MacOS comes with Bash 3.2 (the last version under GPL 2) for licensing reasons. Bash 3.2 fails on line 17 for 2 reasons (which is line 6 of the heredoc):
1. For some reason, the `<(` generates 2 file descriptors, which is why it's saying `ambiguous redirect`. This could be fixed by using a single set of double-quotes: `"$file_dir/{,.}$file_name*"`.
2. The `mapfile` builtin wasn't added until Bash 4.0.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky This script doesn't work with the builtin MacOS Bash 3.2. I think it could be made to work by removing the `mapfile` line and setting `backup_count` to `"$(( $(ls -A "$file_dir/"{,.}"$file_name"* 2>/dev/null | wc -l) ))""`.

Comment: @JanKatins The gist version should work with Bash 3.2.

Answer (score 12):

You can use fingerprint for getting sudo access in the terminal or iTerm, just add `auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so` to the first line to your `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file.

Comment: It might be interesting for other to know that the current iTerm version v3.2.8 doesn't allow this when another default option is set. You have to go into Preferences -> Advanced and deactivate `Allow sessions to survive logging out and back in`: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/7608#note_153123852

Answer (score 9):

To wrap up Andy and Glenjamin's solution into one play:

```yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: install pam_reattach pam module
    homebrew:
      name: pam-reattach
      state: present
    register: reattach_result

  - name: detect touch id support
    shell: pgrep ControlStrip
    ignore_errors: true
    register: touch_id_result

  - name: enable touch id for sudo commands
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/pam.d/sudo
      line: 'auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so'
      insertbefore: '^auth       sufficient     pam_smartcard.so$'
    become: yes
    when: touch_id_result.rc == 0 and touch_id_result.stdout != ''

  - name: enable persistent touch id for tmux and iterm
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/pam.d/sudo
      line: 'auth       optional       pam_reattach.so'
      insertbefore: '^auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so$'
    become: yes
    when: reattach_result == 0
```

This can be run with just `ansible-playbook sudo-touchid.yml`, where `sudo-touchid.yml` is what I named this play.

The first step installs Fabian's `pam_reattach`, which allows sudo to work in iTerm, tmux, etc.

The second checks to see if this Mac has a touchbar; otherwise we're going to bail out.

Third, we're seeing if we already added `pam_tid.so` to `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, and only if there is a touchbar.

Finally, we also add `pam_reattach.so` as an `optional` auth method. According to the author, he might have have some unknown bug, and if we used `required` it could result in a lockout.

Comment: This answer may benefit from an explanation on how to actually use it and why the different parts are necessary.

Comment: Turns out `pgrep ControlStrip` succeeds also on my M1 Max MBP 2021, even if it has no touchbar any more.

Comment: really? I have a M1 Max MBP 2021 on macOS 12.6.2 (Monterey, ARM) and there is no ControlStrip process.

Comment: On my M2 homebrew installs the PAM module to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pam-reattach/1.3/lib/pam/pam_reattach.so` so PAM doesn't find it. Then one is logged out.

Comment: This is how I test for the presence of Touch ID: `test $(bioutil -sr | sed -n 's/\([[:space:]]\+\)Biometrics functionality: \([[:digit:]]\+\)$/\2/p') -gt 0`.

Answer (score 7):

Open `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local.template`. I used BBEdit.

Uncomment the 3rd line `#auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so`

Save as `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local`.

The first line of `/etc/pam.d/sudo` already includes this `_local` file:
`auth       include        sudo_local`

TouchID should now be an authorization method for Terminal.app, and should survive updates etc.

Comment: I think this new for MacOS 14 Sonoma

Comment: I guess that makes this the most current (and correct) answer then :)

Answer (score 3):

I created the following ansible tasks to enable touch id for sudo commands if your computer supports it:

```
- name: detect touch id support
  shell: pgrep ControlStrip
  ignore_errors: true
  register: touch_id_result

- name: enable touch id for sudo commands
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/pam.d/sudo
    line: 'auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so'
    insertbefore: '^auth       sufficient     pam_smartcard.so$'
  become: yes
  when: touch_id_result.rc == 0 and touch_id_result.stdout != ''
```

Answer (score 3):

My 1 string answer:

```
sudo su root -c 'chmod +w /etc/pam.d/sudo && echo "auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so\n$(cat /etc/pam.d/sudo)" > /etc/pam.d/sudo && chmod -w /etc/pam.d/sudo'
```

What does a command do?

1. First, I indicate that I want to do everything [from root](https://superuser.com/posts/777349/revisions) (using
   sudo, the trick will not work ([more precisely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/550808/4121942), it will, but more
   difficult to implement)
2. Then I give write permissions to
   /etc/pam.d/sudo
3. Then I add the line `auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so` to
   the beginning of the file. See [that post](https://superuser.com/a/521654)
4. Then I take away the
   granted write permissions /etc/pam.d/sudo , taking
   into account [Matin ZD remarks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411390/422277)

P.S.
While experimenting broke sudo and su in the terminal, it is repaired like this
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012 enable root

```
su - root
vim /etc/pam.d/sudo
```

Revert the file to its original state

Comment: The PS just saved my life! But I needed the English link not the Russian one (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012), so I sent an edit.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner will insert the auth line described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306324/19025) as the second line of the `sudo` config file (so that it appears first after the comment line).

```bsh
sudo sed -i -- '2s/^/auth sufficient pam_tid.so\n/' /etc/pam.d/sudo
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Gist to make it as simple as possible.

https://gist.github.com/fraune/0831edc01fa89f46ce43b8bbc3761ac7

Comment: Please summarise your Gist into this answer. Link-only answers are not preferred here, as if the link disappears, your answer is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to mention is that you should first change the file permission then try to make changes:

```
sudo su -
chmod u+w /etc/pam.d/sudo
```

Adding this line at first line:

```
# sudo: auth account password session
auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so # << Add this here ;)
auth       sufficient     pam_smartcard.so
auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
account    required       pam_permit.so
password   required       pam_deny.so
session    required       pam_permit.so
```

Then revert it back file permissions when you are done with:

`chmod u-w /etc/pam.d/sudo`

Comment: I've been doing and recommending this change for years and never heard of anyone needing to do this. If this is sometimes necessary, I think explaining when would be useful, otherwise this appears to be completely extraneous.

Comment: I had a focus on permissions, not for that line ;) @grg Also If you want to change the file or write to it by default the file permission is 444 which is not writable by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the top comment of Michael https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306324/388071 the Touch ID permissions process can be simplied by just opening Terminal (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>: 'Terminal'), and run: `echo 'auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so' | sudo tee -a /etc/pam.d/sudo` with your admin user password

[image]

Note that TouchID also gets automatically disabled *after* each **MacOS update**. To automatically re-enable the touch ID running this command you will add an automatic repair check to your bash profile:

```
echo 'if ! grep -q "pam_tid.so" /etc/pam.d/sudo; then
  echo "Updating /etc/pam.d/sudo to activate Touch ID authentication permissions from Terminal:"
  echo 'auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so' | sudo tee -a /etc/pam.d/sudo
  echo "pam_tid.so permissions updated:\n\n$(cat /etc/pam.d/sudo)"
fi' >> .bashrc # Change this to `>> .zshrc` when using Oh-My-Zsh
```