# How can I let apps make changes using TouchID on MacBook Pro?

Tags: touch-bar

How can I allow an app to make changes without typing in the password, but using TouchID on the Touch Bar instead?

MacBook Pro, 13", 2016, macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Example:[image: Example prompt]

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306324/6126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not one of the supported features of Touch ID on macOS - at least not *yet*.

With Touch ID on your MBP, you can:

- unlock your Mac
- make purchases using your Apple ID (i.e. from the App Store and iTunes)
- use Apple Pay

Undoubtedly as time goes by, more functionality will be added to Touch ID on macOS - but the ability to use it to allow apps to make changes to macOS isn't available yet.