MacBook Pro approve as administrator with an apple watch in clamshell
I have enjoyed the seamless integration and convenience offered by the Apple Watch to unlock my MacBook and authorize various actions without the need for password inputs. This has been particularly useful when my MacBook Pro's lid is closed and I'm operating in clamshell mode with external peripherals. But I don't know when behavior changes.
Detailed Description of the Issue:
With my 16-inch MacBook Pro, 2019 model (intel), I have noticed a change in how the system responds to authentication requests. While I can still unlock my MacBook Pro using my Apple Watch, I am no longer able to authorize certain actions, such as using sudo in the terminal or accessing applications like Dashlane. Previously, my Apple Watch would facilitate these actions without requiring me to input a password, even with the MacBook lid closed. This has changed; now, when my MacBook Pro lid is closed, I am compelled to enter passwords manually for actions that my Apple Watch should authorize. Or quip it open.
If anyone has a hint on how to troubleshoot this issue, it will be appreciated.

This Apple Support Page discusses these two authorization schemes. It is both or nothing, so something is awry. I suggest you go to System Settings > Login Password and disable the Apple Watch, close the System Setting panel, the re-enable the Watch. Sometimes changing a Setting configuration fixes things.

Could it be due to the fact that I modified the /etc/pam.d/sudo file and glitched everything? I did disable and reenable it, but it still doesn't work.

Update I get ask when I go in Settings > Password so it sudo in terminal and dashlane that are the problem (only when the lid is closed) do you have any idea ? @IconDaemon

same as this :

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255182555?sortBy=best
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411497/pam-tid-so-asks-for-password-instead-of-requesting-for-fingerprint-when-docked/444202#444202


No idea, Guillaume. Both actions work with two computers at home, and worked last week on my work Mac. I don't know what the  /etc/pam.d/sudo file is, TBH. Good luck!

I use a GitHub project for pam-watchid:

clone the project & make
git clone https://github.com/biscuitehh/pam-watchid /tmp/pam-watchid
cd /tmp/pam-watchid
make install


⚠️ WARNING
Misconfiguration can disrupt your sudo, but modifying PAM requires sudo privileges. If misconfigured, you may lose the ability to use sudo, like a snake biting its own tail. To prevent losing sudo access, do the following:

Create a backup!
sudo cp /etc/pam.d/sudo_local /etc/pam.d/sudo_local.bak
Open another sudo terminal (I once lost the root on my mac).
2. Then configure the sudo nano /etc/pam.d/sudo_local file.


# sudo_local: local config file which survives system update and is included for sudo
auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so
auth sufficient pam_watchid.so "reason=execute a command as root"

See Configuring MacOS to Use Apple Watch or Touch ID for MFA With Sudo for a helpful guide and the pam-watchid GitHub for more details.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Thank you for the remark, I think it's better!

Nice! If you want to ask a follow on question on brave app, that would be good now better than asking for a second answer in the comments to this answer

I will do that
